# Search a table name across multiple databases SQL SERVER 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server, for-loop, conditional-statements

I have a table, and the table name is AADatatimeBB in DatabaseB.

My SQL service Have  multiple databases DatabaseA,DatabaseB,DatabaseC,DatabaseD

If I do not know the table: AADatatimeBB in which Database, how can I search it?

I can use the following query to search the table if I know the table in which Database.

Select the Database Name in the available Database list and run the query

SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
where table_name like '%DATASET%'

Comment: [master].[sys].[databases] contains all databases of the server.

Comment: A well documented application *should* tell you what the name of the database the application is using as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following query you can retrieve the names of all databases.

```
SELECT name, database_id, create_date  
FROM sys.databases ;  
GO  

OR-----------------------------------

SELECT *
FROM sys.databases ;  
GO
```

If you want the names of tables in a database, you can use the following query

```
USE master 
GO
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.tables
GO  

OR----------------------------

USE model 
GO
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.tables
GO  

OR-----------------------

USE ... 
GO
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.tables
GO
```

The following code retrieves all databases and returns all tables of each database in a while loop.

```
Declare @tempTable Table
(
  name varchar(100)
)
--Container to Insert records in the inner select for final output

Insert into @tempTable 
SELECT name
FROM sys.databases 


-- Keep track of @tempTable record processing
Declare @name varchar(100)
Declare @SQL VarChar(1000)

While((Select Count(*) From @tempTable)>0)
Begin
  Set @name=(Select Top 1 name From @tempTable)
  --get all db tables
  SELECT @SQL = 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@name) + ' SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables' 
  Exec (@SQL)
  Delete @tempTable Where name=@name
End
```

If you want to use `SQL LIKE Operator`, follow the code below

```
SELECT @SQL = 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@name) + ' SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name LIKE ''%a%'''
```

Comment: Hi Meysam, the query:USE master 
GO
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.tables
GO  only search the table in the master table. If I do not know the database name, I cannot search the table name

Comment: I changed the code. You can achieve the desired result with a little change. First I recovered all the databases. Then I retrieved the tables of each database.

Comment: Careful, if the OP has any databases that require delimit identification this'll error. You should quote the objects properly, with `QUOTENAME`, when injecting dynamic object names.

Comment: Hi Meysam, the script works for listing all tables. how can I add my where conditions? where table_name like '%DATASET%' SELECT @SQL = 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@name) + ' SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables where table_name like '%DATASET%'' Error message: Invalid column name 'DATASET'.

Comment: @Anson I added the use of the like operator at the end of the answer.